# 2 problems with registration

Tags: django

I use the obvious powerful registration 0.8 alpha version. I do have to questions.

1.) I want to add the checkbox RegistrationTermsOfService at the registration form html file. I just don't know how to do it. Please don't give me an link on uebernstorm docs. Just tell me please how to do it. I have read and tried a lot and it actually doesn't work. I am dispairing!

2.) The activation email is send with the activation key. When I click on activation the account is getting activated in the database but the template says something different. It says:"Sorry, it didn't work. Either..."

I use the standard activate.html below:
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Account activated{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  Account activated
  {% load humanize %}
  {% if account %}

Thanks for signing up! Now you can "href"

{% else %}

Sorry, it didn't work. Either your activation link was incorrect, or
    the activation key for your account has expired; activation keys are
    only valid for {{ expiration_days|apnumber }} days after
    registration.

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

PLEASE, PLEASE help me!!! I am dispairing!!!

Craphunter

Answer (score 0):

For 1) you need to use a different form. Look in registration.forms for the one you need and pass it as an additional argument in the backend's urls.py

For 2) we'll need more info - is the URL correct? Is there a RegistrationProfile object created for the user account in question? What is the value of the key?